# regex to match non ascii characters with alphanumeric or without alphanumeric

Tags: regex

I have a String like this.

```
   <sas Value="����������"/>
   <abc Value="���������"/>
```

I want to match **non-ascii** characters between Value attributes whether alphanumeric characters are present or not.

I want to match whole Strings if contains **non-ASCII** characters.

with the below regex I am able to match the string if alphanumeric is in the beginning or at the end.
But I am not able to match if alphanumeric is in between.

https://regex101.com/r/L3cbU7/3

```
   <sas Value="����������"/> -- matching(it should match)
   <abc Value="abc���������abc"/> -- matching(it should match)
   <abc Value="����sasa�����"/> -- not matching(it should match)
```

with the above example, the last one is not matching.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `<((?!UnitConfigCode|UNP_serNo|UNP_partNo)[\w]+) Value=".*?[^\x20-\x7E].*?"(\s?)+\/>`. `.*?[^\x20-\x7E].*?` basically means "at least one `[^\x20-\x7E]` between `.`'s".

I have also removed a backslash that seemed redundant.

https://regex101.com/r/L3cbU7/6.